# How to load external fonts via javascript before page ready

Tags: javascript, fonts, webfonts, typekit

I'm using typekit on my website to load fonts and typekit gives me 2 links.

```
<script src="https://use.typekit.net/xxxx.js"></script>
<script>try { Typekit.load({ async: false }); } catch (e) { }</script>
```

I put these links in head tag but when I enter my website fonts are loaded after content. I wonder how can it load before page ready or before content load.

PS: I tried async: true and false.. Both of them gave same result.

Comment: Are there any other lines between font links and `<head>`? This may cause the problem.

Comment: No.. I tried as you said below

Comment: Could you please provide all the code inside your `<head>` element? A live example would facilitate helping you, too.

Comment: I'm using like this:

<head>
    <script src="https://use.typekit.net/xxxxx.js"></script>
        @*<script>try { Typekit.load({ async: false }); } catch (e) { }   </script>*@

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function preloadFunc()
    {
        try { Typekit.load({ async: false }); } catch (e) { }
    }
    window.onpaint = preloadFunc();
    </script>
<meta>.....
<title>....
</head>

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can use is *Font Evens* to hide content while the fonts load. https://helpx.adobe.com/typekit/using/font-events.html

Comment: I guess this is only way but I didn't like it but I think I am going to use css like that.

.wf-loading h1, .wf-loading h2, .wf-loading h3, .wf-loading p, .wf-loading span, .wf-loading a, .wf-loading button, .wf-loading input[type=submit]{
visibibility:hidden;
}

Comment: You could also implement a loading screen. From UX standpoint it's a bit more annoying but looks better.

Comment: Yes you are right but I wish it was a solution that fonts are downloaded via js before content load. Thank you so much to everyone for help

Answer (score 0):

You can try `window.onpaint` if simply putting font links to `<head>` is not working.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://use.typekit.net/xxxx.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function preloadFunc()
    {
        try { Typekit.load({ async: false }); } catch (e) { }
    }
    window.onpaint = preloadFunc();
</script>
```